# How to optimize slow LINQ query?

Tags: performance, entity-framework, linq

I tried delete a statement that use contain() and use skip() take()
but it's still take a long time on execution

```
    public JsonNetResult GetList(C.Lib.ListParam param, string type, DateTime? WorkDate, string MNo, string ANo, string AName, string Specifi, string PNo, string SName, string PType, string OrNo)
    {
        var idObj = (mis.Models.Security.CIdentity)Csla.ApplicationContext.User.Identity;
        var c = new mis.Models.CEntities();
        var targetList = (from obj in c.WorkOrders
                          join obj2 in c.Partners on obj.PartnerId equals obj2.PartnerId
                          join obj3 in c.Assets on obj.AssetsId equals obj3.AssetsId
                          join obj4 in c.WorkOrderItems on obj.WorkOrderId equals obj4.WorkOrderId
                          join obj5 in c.WorkItems on obj4.WorkId equals obj5.WorkId
                          join obj6 in c.Products on obj3.AssetsId equals obj6.AssetsId
                          where true && obj.TenantId == idObj.TenantId && obj2.Customer == true && obj.WorkOrderStatus <= 1
                          select new
                          {
                              WorkProgressId = obj.WorkOrderId,
                              OrderNo = obj.InOrderItem.OrderItem.Order.OrderNo,
                              ProductType = obj5.ProductType,
                              WorkOrderId = obj.WorkOrderId,
                              MakeQty = obj.MakeQty,//delete some column
                              PrepaidDate = obj.PrepaidDate,
                              CompleteDate = (from subobj in c.WorkOrderItems
                                              where subobj.WorkOrderId == obj.WorkOrderId && subobj.CompleteDate != null
                                              orderby subobj.CompleteDate descending, subobj.WorkItem.WorkNo descending
                                              select subobj.CompleteDate).FirstOrDefault(),

                              WorkNoName = (from subobj in c.WorkOrderItems
                                            where subobj.WorkOrderId == obj.WorkOrderId && subobj.CompleteDate != null
                                            orderby  subobj.WorkItem.WorkNo descending
                                            select new { WorkNoName = subobj.WorkItem.WorkNo + " " + subobj.WorkItem.WorkName }).FirstOrDefault().WorkNoName,

                          });
        targetList = targetList.GroupBy(x => x.MakeNo).Select(x => new
        {
            WorkProgressId = x.FirstOrDefault().WorkOrderId,
            OrderNo = x.FirstOrDefault().OrderNo,
            ProductType = x.FirstOrDefault().ProductType,
            WorkOrderId = x.FirstOrDefault().WorkOrderId,
            WorkOrderDate = x.FirstOrDefault().WorkOrderDate,
            OrderQty = x.FirstOrDefault().OrderQty,
            MakeQty = x.FirstOrDefault().MakeQty,
            PrepaidDate = x.FirstOrDefault().PrepaidDate,//delete some column
            CompleteDate = x.FirstOrDefault().CompleteDate,

            WorkNoName = x.FirstOrDefault().WorkNoName
        }).OrderByDescending(x => x.WorkOrderDate).ThenByDescending(x => x.WorkNoName);

        param.SetCount(targetList);
        targetList.OrderByDescending(x => x.WorkOrderDate).ThenByDescending(x=> x.WorkNoName);
        var tk= targetList.Skip((param.Page - 1) * param.Rows).Take(param.Rows);
        return JsonNetHelper.ReturnData(param,tk);
    }
```

I'm wondering what is the best way to optimize it? Or would the query profiler do that for me?

Comment: Did you view the SQL query that it generated? [link](Here's how to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412863/how-do-i-view-the-sql-generated-by-the-entity-framework).  You can try to run it in SQL Server Management Studio, view the execution plan, and see if it gives recommendations on creating indexes or other optimizations.

Comment: I think you should denormilize your tables to exclude some joins and subqueries.